# Random number in Do While Loop

Tags: c#, random, while-loop, do-while, random-seed

I have been trying to create a random string out of alphanumeric characters and to use Do-While Loop to check if the random string meet the requirement. Otherwise, it should continue the Do Loop. However, I found the code I have always generates the same string over and over again. To demonstrate, I set `int message_length = 2` and ask While Loop to check if the generated string is "ab" like `while (check != "ab")`.

I have tried to put `Random seed = new Random()` in the Do Loop, out of the Do Loop, and out of the Main() as you can see the code I commented out. None of them is working. I used Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10 Home. Anyone could help? Many thanks!

(Further comments: Although I got the code working fine now, I still don't understand why the original line `check = all_message.ToString();` can interrupt the random number generator in this case. IMHO, the while condition `while (check != "ab")` is still True so the loop will keep going. But why Random Number Generator stop generating new seed? Anyone could share knowledge about this?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    //static Random seed = new Random();

    public static void Main(string[] arggs)
    {
        Random seed = new Random();
        const string src = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        Console.WriteLine(src.Length);
        int string_length = 2;
        List<string> all_message = new List<string>();
        string check = "";
        do
        {
            //Random seed = new Random();
            int i = 0;
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < string_length; j++)
            {
                char c = src[seed.Next(0, src.Length)];
                message.Append(c);
            }
            all_message.Add(message.ToString());
            check = all_message.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + all_message[i]);

            i++;
        }
        while (check != "ab");

    }
}
```

Comment: `check = message.ToString();`? TBH, it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The type of `all_message` is `StringBuilder`. So I need `check = message.ToString()` to convert it to string type.

Comment: Ok. But in the code you have `check = all_message.ToString();` which is converting the list to string.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp don't confuse OP - `all_message.ToString();` - doesn't "convert the list to string" but simply "returns name of List's type"... (which obviously will never be "ab", but that's for OP to debug)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In the `all_message.Add(message.ToString())`, `message.ToString()` is to convert `StringBuilder` to `string` type. `check = all_message.ToString()` is to convert `list` to `string` type.

Comment: 2 things: 1. `check` will *ALWAYS* be 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' (yes, that string literally). I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing. 2. Why do you think your loop is generating the same string? Just put a breakpoint where you assign `c` and see if it changes. I bet it does.

Comment: The code is working in my system, and there is no error. The question is what I mentioned about random number.

Comment: [Use your debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to look at what `check` is. It isn't what you think it is. We can't help because we don't understand what you're trying to do. A `List<string>` cannot ever possibly be equal to `ab`.

Comment: Many thanks for all your quick reply. It is the issue of `check = all_message.ToString();` I used debug, but never check this line since it didn't give any error message. But now I figured out and will post a solution soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting your counter 'i' on every iteration of the loop, so you will always write the first element of the generated list to the console. Initialize i outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

With the help from others, I figured out the issue. The critical change is `check = string.Join("", all_message.ToArray());`. With few other minor changes, the solutions is here:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    //static Random seed = new Random();

    public static void Main(string[] arggs)
    {
        Random seed = new Random();
        const string src = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        Console.WriteLine(src.Length);
        int string_length = 2;
        string check = "";
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            //Random seed = new Random();
            List<string> all_message = new List<string>();

            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < string_length; j++)
            {
                char c = src[seed.Next(0, src.Length)];
                message.Append(c);
            }
            all_message.Add(message.ToString());
            check = string.Join("", all_message.ToArray());
            //Console.WriteLine(check);
            Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + check);

            i++;
        }
        while (check != "ab");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following:

```
Random seed = new Random();
const string src = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
Console.WriteLine(src.Length);
int string_length = 2;
List<string> all_message = new List<string>();
string check = "";
int i = 0;
do
{
    //Random seed = new Random();
    
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < string_length; j++)
    {
        char c = src[seed.Next(0, src.Length)];
        message.Append(c);      
    }   
    all_message.Add(message.ToString());
    check = all_message.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + all_message[i]);
    i++;
}
while (i < 3);
```

My output was:

```
62
0 = PQ
1 = xw
2 = he
```

Note that the index `i` is initialised outside the loop and so it not reset every time through.

The question then becomes, what are your requirements and when to terminate the loop and what should `check` be?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Read the comments.

```
        Random seed = new Random();
        const string src = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        Console.WriteLine(src.Length);
        int string_length = 2;
        List<string> all_message = new List<string>();
        string check = "";
        do
        {
            //Random seed = new Random(); -- you do not need it any more hier.

            int i = 0; // if you whant counting with i, put it above the do while.

            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

            for (int j = 0; j < string_length; j++)
            {
                char c = src[seed.Next(0, src.Length)];
                message.Append(c);
            }


            all_message.Add(message.ToString());

            check = all_message.ToString(); // this is the list from string you do not need it realy and list to string  = System.Collections.Generics.List....
            //instead check should be equal to all_message[i] case i counting properly

            Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + all_message[i]); // and hier simply print the check, you allready have the value.

            i++;
        }
        while (check != "ab");
```